# How do we unit test spring integration xml configuration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am new to spring integration and currently stuck on unit testing my integration flow. My flow looks something like this.

1. Recieve some data from TCP channel adapter in XML format.
2. Convert it to JSON.
3. Send JSON message to amazon sqs queue.

and XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
   xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
   xmlns:aws-messaging="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging 
   https://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/messaging/spring-cloud-aws-messaging.xsd">

<!-- -->
<!-- receive callbacks -->
<!-- -->
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
        id="inboundServerTCPFactory1"
        deserializer="customSerializerDeserializer"
        serializer="customSerializerDeserializer"
        type="server"
        port="8085"
        using-nio="true"
        single-use="true"/>

<!-- -->
<!-- receive callbacks -->
<!-- -->
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory
        id="inboundServerTCPFactory2"
        deserializer="customSerializerDeserializer"
        serializer="customSerializerDeserializer"
        type="server"
        port="8086"
        using-nio="true"
        single-use="true"/>

<!-- -->
<!-- Inbound channel adapter -->
<!-- -->
<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelAdapter1"
                                    channel="inboundReceivingChannel"
                                    connection-factory="inboundServerTCPFactory1"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelAdapter2"
                                    channel="inboundReceivingChannel"
                                    connection-factory="inboundServerTCPFactory2"/>

<!-- -->
<!-- Inbound channel adapter -->
<!-- -->
<int:channel id="inboundReceivingChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>


<!--Transfrom XML message to Json-->
<int:transformer ref="xmlToJsonTransformer" input-channel="inboundReceivingChannel"
                 method="transform" output-channel="outChannel"/>

<int:channel id="outChannel" />

<!--<aws-messaging:sqs-async-client id="amazonSqs"/>-->

<int-aws:sqs-outbound-channel-adapter id= "out"
                                      sqs="sqs"
                                      channel="outChannel"
                                      queue="SendQueue"/>
</beans>
```

How do I mock every component and unit test the complete flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Spring Integration testing support documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing. The framework provides for us a `MockIntegrationContext` via `@SpringIntegrationTest` marker on the Spring JUnit test class. The `MockIntegration` factory lets us to create respective mocks and stub their handling logic. Then you can substitute endpoint beans with your mocks and so.

Comment: Thank you, Artem. I was able to mock endpoints with the documentation provided.